# Resolving a 'model empty' error in cross-validation for SVM classification when using the CMA Bioconductor package for R

Tags: r, classification, svm, bioconductor

I am using the Bioconductor package [CMA](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/CMA.html) to perform internal, Monte Carlo cross-validation (MCCV) on SVM classifiers in a microarray dataset. CMA internally uses the e1071 R package for the SVM work.

The dataset has 387 variables (attributes) for 45 samples (observations) which belong to one of two classes (labels 0 or 1; at about 1:1 proportion). All data is numerical with no NAs. I am trying a 1000-iteration MCCV with 15 variables selected for SVM using the [limma statistics](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/limma/html/ebayes.html) for differential gene expression analysis. During MCCV, a fraction of the 45-sample set is used for training an SVM classifier, which is then used to test the remaining fraction, and I am trying different values for the training-set fraction. CMA also performs inner-loop validations (3-fold cross-validation within the training sets, by default) to fine-tune the classifiers to be used for cross-validation against the test-sets. All this is done from within the CMA package.

Sometimes, for low training-set sizes, CMA shows an error in the console and halts the rest of the code for classification from getting executed.

```
[snip]tuning iteration 575
tuning iteration 576
tuning iteration 577
Error in predict.svm(ret, xhold, decision.values = TRUE) :   Model is empty!
```

It occurs even when I use a test other than limma's for variable selection, or use two instead of 15 variables for classifier generation. The R code I use should ensure that the training-sets always have members of both classes. I would appreciate any insight on this.

Below is the R code I use, with Mac OS X 10.6.6, R 2.12.1, Biobase 2.10.0, CMA 1.8.1, limma 3.6.9, and WilcoxCV 1.0.2. The data file hy3ExpHsaMir.txt can be downloaded from http://rapidshare.com/files/447062901/hy3ExpHsaMir.txt.

Everything goes OK until *g* is 9 in the *for(g in 0:10)* loop (for varying the training/test-set sizes).

```
# exp is the expression table, a matrix; 'classes' is list of known classes
exp <- as.matrix(read.table(file='hy3ExpHsaMir.txt', sep='\t', row.names=1, header=T, check.names=F))
#best is to use 0 and 1 as class labels (instead of 'p', 'g', etc.) with 1 for 'positive' items (positive for recurrence, or for disease, etc.)
classes <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
yesPredVal = 1 # class label for 'positive' items in 'classes'

library(CMA)
library(WilcoxCV)
myNumFun <- function(x, y){round(y(as.numeric(x), na.rm=T), 4)}
set.seed(631)
out = ''
out2 = '\nEffect of varying the training-set size:\nTraining-set size\tSuccessful iterations\tMean acc.\tSD acc.\tMean sens.\tSD sens.\tMean spec.\tSD spec.\tMean PPV\tSD PPV\tMean NPV\tSD NPV\tTotal genes in the classifiers\n'

niter = 1000
diffTest = 'limma'
diffGeneNum = 15
svmCost <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50)

for(g in 0:10){ # varying the training/test-set sizes
 ntest = 3+g*3 # test-set size
 result <- matrix(nrow=0, ncol=7)
 colnames(result) <- c('trainSetSize', 'iteration', 'acc', 'sens', 'spec', 'ppv', 'npv')
 diffGenes <- numeric()

 # generate training and test sets
 lsets <- GenerateLearningsets(n=ncol(exp), y=classes, method=c('MCCV'), niter=niter, ntrain=ncol(exp)-ntest)

 # actual prediction work
 svm <- classification(t(exp), factor(classes), learningsets=lsets, genesellist= list(method=diffTest), classifier=svmCMA, nbgene= diffGeneNum, tuninglist=list(grids=list(cost=svmCost)), probability=TRUE)
 svm <- join(svm)
 # genes in classifiers
 svmGenes <- GeneSelection(t(exp), classes, learningsets=lsets, method=diffTest)

 actualIters=0
 for(h in 1:niter){
  m <- ntest*(h-1)
  # valid SVM classification requires min. 2 classes
  if(1 < length(unique(classes[-lsets@learnmatrix[h,]]))){
   actualIters = actualIters+1
   tp <- tn <- fp <- fn <- 0
   for(i in 1:ntest){
    pred <- svm@yhat[m+i]
    known <- svm@y[m+i]
    if(pred == known){
     if(pred == yesPredVal){tp <- tp+1}
     else{tn <- tn+1}
    }else{
     if(pred == yesPredVal){fp <- fp+1}
     else{fn <- fn+1}
    }
   }
   result <- rbind(result, c(ncol(exp)-ntest, h, (tp+tn)/(tp+tn+fp+fn), tp/(tp+fn), tn/(tn+fp), tp/(tp+fp), tn/(tn+fn)))
   diffGenes <- c(diffGenes, toplist(svmGenes, k=diffGeneNum, iter=h, show=F)$index)
  } # end if valid SVM
 } # end for h

 # output accuracy, etc.
 out = paste(out, 'SVM MCCV using ',  niter, ' attempted iterations and ', actualIters, ' successful iterations, with ', ncol(exp)-ntest, ' of ', ncol(exp), ' total samples used for training:\nThe means (ranges; SDs) of prediction accuracy, sensitivity, specificity, PPV and NPV in fractions are ', 
myNumFun(result[, 'acc'],mean), ' (', myNumFun(result[, 'acc'], min), '-', myNumFun(result[, 'acc'], max), '; ', myNumFun(result[, 'acc'], sd), '), ', 
 myNumFun(result[, 'sens'], mean), ' (', myNumFun(result[, 'sens'], min), '-', myNumFun(result[, 'sens'], max), '; ', myNumFun(result[, 'sens'], sd), '), ', 
 myNumFun(result[, 'spec'], mean), ' (', myNumFun(result[, 'spec'], min), '-', myNumFun(result[, 'spec'], max), '; ', myNumFun(result[, 'spec'], sd), '), ', 
 myNumFun(result[, 'ppv'], mean), ' (', myNumFun(result[, 'ppv'], min), '-', myNumFun(result[, 'ppv'], max), '; ', myNumFun(result[, 'ppv'], sd), '), and ', 
 myNumFun(result[, 'npv'], mean), ' (', myNumFun(result[, 'npv'], min), '-', myNumFun(result[, 'npv'], max), '; ', myNumFun(result[, 'npv'], sd), '), respectively.\n', sep='')

 # output classifier genes
 diffGenesUnq <- unique(diffGenes)
 out = paste(out, 'A total of ', length(diffGenesUnq), ' genes occur in the ', actualIters, ' classifiers, with occurrence frequencies in fractions:\n', sep='')
 for(i in 1:length(diffGenesUnq)){
  out = paste(out, rownames(exp)[diffGenesUnq[i]], '\t', round(sum(diffGenes == diffGenesUnq[i])/actualIters, 3), '\n', sep='')
 }

 # output split-size effect
 out2 = paste(out2, ncol(exp)-ntest, '\t', actualIters, '\t', myNumFun(result[, 'acc'], mean), '\t', myNumFun(result[, 'acc'], sd), '\t', myNumFun(result[, 'sens'], mean), '\t', myNumFun(result[, 'sens'], sd), '\t', myNumFun(result[, 'spec'], mean), '\t', myNumFun(result[, 'spec'], sd), '\t', myNumFun(result[, 'ppv'], mean), '\t', myNumFun(result[, 'ppv'], sd), 
'\t', myNumFun(result[, 'npv'], mean), '\t', myNumFun(result[, 'npv'], sd), '\t', length(diffGenesUnq), '\n', sep='')
} # end for g

cat(out, out2, sep='')
```

Output for traceback():

```
20: stop("Model is empty!")
19: predict.svm(ret, xhold, decision.values = TRUE)
18: predict(ret, xhold, decision.values = TRUE)
17: na.action(predict(ret, xhold, decision.values = TRUE))
16: svm.default(cost = 0.1, kernel = "linear", type = "C-classification", ...
15: svm(cost = 0.1, kernel = "linear", type = "C-classification", ...
14: do.call("svm", args = ll)
13: function (X, y, f, learnind, probability, models = FALSE, ...) ...
12: function (X, y, f, learnind, probability, models = FALSE, ...) ...
11: do.call(classifier, args = c(list(X = X, y = y, learnind = learnmatrix[i, ...
10: classification(X = c(83.5832768669369, 83.146333099001, 94.253534443549, ...
9: classification(X = c(83.5832768669369, 83.146333099001, 94.253534443549, ...
8: do.call("classification", args = c(list(X = Xi, y = yi, learningsets = lsi, ...
7: tune(grids = list(cost = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50...
6: tune(grids = list(cost = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50...
5: do.call("tune", args = c(tuninglist, ll))
4: classification(X, y = as.numeric(y) - 1, learningsets = learningsets, ...
3: classification(X, y = as.numeric(y) - 1, learningsets = learningsets, ...
2: classification(t(exp), factor(classes), learningsets = lsets, ...
1: classification(t(exp), factor(classes), learningsets = lsets, ...
```

Comment: Without data this is impossible to test.

Comment: This may be something you should try discussing with the package author.

Comment: I have added a link for the data file in the original post.

Answer (score 3):

The maintainer of the CMA package promptly responded to a message I had sent about this issue.

CMA tunes a classifier generated from a training-set by testing different parameter values in a within-training-set, k-fold CV step (default k=3). With small training-set sizes, this inner loop can fail if observations of only one class get sub-setted. Two ways to reduce the chance of this happening are to do a 2-fold inner CV, and to specify stratified sampling, both of which require that the tuning step is invoked separately through CMA's *tune()* and use its output in *classification()*.

In the code I posted, tuning is invoked from within *classification()*, which doesn't allow for stratified sampling or 2-fold CV. However, invoking *tune()* separately, for stratified sampling and 2-fold CV, did not help in my case. This is not surprising as, with small training-sets, CMA encounters cases with sets of members of only one class.

I wish that instead of abruptly ending everything, CMA would continue working on the remaining learning sets when it encounters such an issue with one learning set. It would also be nice if, when having this issue, CMA would try different values of k for the inner k-fold CV step.

[Edited on Feb. 14] CMA's generation of learning-sets for CV does not check if sufficient members of both classes exist in a training set. The following replacement for a portion of the code in the original post should therefore make things work properly:

```
numInnerFold = 3 # k for the k-fold inner validation called through tune()
# generate learning-sets with 2*niter members in case some have to be removed
lsets <- GenerateLearningsets(n=ncol(exp), y=classes, method=c('MCCV'), niter=2*niter, ntrain=ncol(exp)-ntest)
temp <- lsets@learnmatrix
for(i in 1:(2*niter)){
 unq <- unique(classes[lsets@learnmatrix[i, ]])
 if((2 > length(unique(classes[lsets@learnmatrix[i, ]])))
    | (numInnerFold > sum(classes[lsets@learnmatrix[i, ]] == yesPredVal))
    | (numInnerFold > sum(classes[lsets@learnmatrix[i, ]] != yesPredVal))){
  # cat('removed set', i,'\n')
  temp <- lsets@learnmatrix[-i, ]
 }
}
lsets@learnmatrix <- temp[1:niter, ]
lsets@iter <- niter

# genes in classifiers
svmGenes <- GeneSelection(t(exp), classes, learningsets=lsets, method=diffTest)
svmTune <- tune(t(exp), factor(classes), learningsets=lsets, genesel=svmGenes, classifier=svmCMA, nbgene=diffGeneNum, grids=list(cost=svmCost), strat=T, fold=numInnerFold)
# actual prediction work
svm <- classification(t(exp), factor(classes), learningsets=lsets, genesel=svmGenes, classifier=svmCMA, nbgene=diffGeneNum, tuneres=svmTune)
```